# Name error when calling function asking for input from user

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
    days = input("Enter amount of days for car hire")
    city = input("City name")
    days = input("Nights staying")
    spending_money = input("Spending money")
    return hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days) + spending_money

print((trip_cost(city,days,spending_money)))
```

I keep getting an error saying that city is not defined. I am new to Python so I am sorry if this is question that is easy to answer. All the variables already have their set functions. Here is city's one just in case it helps

```
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city=="Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city=="Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city=="Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city=="Los Angeles":
        return 475
    else:
        return input("Please try again")
```

Also this is an altered code from Code Academy

Comment: Where is the error exactly?

Comment: Also note you'll need to convert the strings that `input` gives you to numbers before you can add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `print((trip_cost(city,days,spending_money)))` call, where is city coming from? It looks like it is outside any of the functions so you need to declare it somewhere as something. And even when you do so, you will get the same error for `days` and `spending_money`. These need to be declared before they are printed.

Either that or actually pass in values to your `trip_cost` call in the print statement :)

Also, looking at the code more closely, it looks like your trip_cost method does not even need any arguments. you are creating the variables when asking for input so it looks like they are redundant as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
def trip_cost():
    days = int(input("Enter amount of days for car hire"))
    city = input("City name")
    nights = int(input("Nights staying"))
    spending_money = int(input("Spending money"))
    return hotel_cost(nights) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days) + spending_money

print(trip_cost())
```

Get rid of the parameters; you do not need them since you will get it from user input via the `input()` function.

I used the `int` function to convert the input of numbers which are strings to integers.